# How to add .jar files to a java project manually

Tags: java, server

I'm setting up a server over terminal on which I am running a java file. I am wondering where in the hierarchy I should put the .jar files of a couple libraries that my server needs. My server looks like this right now:

[image: File Hierarchy]

Comment: In a `lib` folder?

Comment: what server your are running? what do you mean by "running a java file"?

Comment: @AdrianShum I already answered my own question if you had scrolled down a little bit

Comment: @multitaskPro If it is a question that does not even make sense, I will suggest deleting it as it leaves no value for reference for other users on StackOverflow site.

Comment: @AdrianShum I tried but the site won't let me, because other people have already tried to answer :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers, but my question was wrong. What I wanted to do was run a java project on a server, but I was trying to do things myself too much. Instead I just compiled my project into a Runnable Jar file using eclipse and then used the command `java -jar *my-filename*.jar to run it.

Answer (score -1):

Check for the .classpath file in the root of the project.Add ur jars there with absolute path

Answer (score -1):

Create a separate lib folder for this and configure your class path to include it. If you are using an IDE like eclipse go to the properties>project dependencies and add the JAR file, it will take care of the location.